# how to import a gradle java project which is inside a nodeJS project in Intellij IDEA

Tags: java, gradle, intellij-idea

I have a project repo where the top layer is structured in nodeJS/npm etc. due to infra setup and internally in one of the directories, the app code which is using JAVA/SpringBoot/Gradle exists.
I am trying to import and set up this repo in IntelliJ IDEA Ultimate to do local setup and development.
Two things I tried:

1. Import the Repo at the top level using Gradle-based import. IntelliJ complained that it did not find any Gradle project in this case.
2. Import the directory that contains the Java project using Gradle-based import. This looks like working.

The question is can I import from the root directory of the project and still have the usual gradle and java capability in IDE?